# Toshiba laptop lid light flickers and lights turn off

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, lcd

I have my laptop for years now and it's still running well but as of couple of months ago there was some color changing on the lower left corner of the screen.

It somewhat appears to be red coloring shade. then, last night the backlight of the LCD turns off while I am starting up the system, but I can still see the desktop on screen. So what I did I closed the lid then waited for it to turn on again then I hold the base of the laptop and position the laptop slanting forward before slowly opening the lid again.

It worked and I was able to post on this site to ask for help. But then again there's the occasional flickering of the backlight and it becomes brighter and the reddish shade no longer that visible on the side.

What could possible happened and what to do to fix it on my own because I can't afford to bring it to computer repair shop.

Answer (score 2):

It is hit or miss when you have to try to figure it out on your own.  You could end up purchasing parts in anticipation of a solution, only to find that they did not solve your problem.

That said, it sounds like your screen inverter is in need of replacement.  You can search youtube for a video detailing how to replace the one in your specific model, which you did not share with us.

Essentially, you remove the screws holding the screen bezel in place ( the plastic frame around the screen ) and you will see a small narrow printed circuit board at the bottom of the LCD panel.  That is the screen inverter.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is a hardware issue, so there is no simple fix that can be provided by someone on the internet. You will have to take your computer to an expert to be repaired.

There are several possibilities
- Bad video card
- Bad LCD
- Bad Inverter
- Bad Motherboard
- Broken connector between motherboard and LCD

Try plugging your Laptop into a TV, or external monitor to see if the issue persists. If the problem goes away, then it is a LCD issue. If the problem persists, then it is a video card / motherboard problem.

Depending on your brand of laptop, these issues could be $150 to $600 to fix. As much as I hate to break it to you, It may be time to shop around for a new laptop.

If you are on a budget, try ebay.com and craigslist.com you can usually find inexpensive used laptops listed. 
Your next best bet will be costco / sams club or any large distributor.